Is my fresh Rosemary still good?
I love using fresh herbs in my recipes, but unfortunately they usually go past their prime before I have a chance to finish them.
It’s easy to spot this because they go limp and lose their “crispness”. However, my new favorite herb is Rosemary, but I notice
that after a few weeks the only problem with it is that it has dried out, but not gone limp or soggy. When chopped up, it doesn’t look any different from the dried Rosemary purchased in the store. Is this herb that’s has gone past it’s prime still safe to eat?

Rosemary is also one of the more satisfying options to grow in a pot and have herbs from,  if you'd like fresh available "whenever." Depending where you live (climate/weather-wise) it can also be grown outdoors (I can do that, but only over the summer.) Had one that kept growing fine for 3 years or more before having a mysterious decline. At least one rooted cutting from that one lives on.

You now have dried rosemary, while different from fresh, perfectly fine to use.

Dry is okay but not ideal. I can definitely taste a difference between fresh and less fresh rosemary. Though I'd be perfectly fine throwing the later in a stew or sizzling in some olive oil, even after a number of weeks in the fridge. But for raw applications, I would try to get fresh rosemary.
Truly bad rosemary, in my experience, turns black, at which point the flavor and texture take a definite turn for the worse. At this point I would relegate it to the compost bin.
